# strange caption numbers in cross-references and list-of-figures

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, captions, subcaption, cleveref

I am trying to fit a large figure containing four subfigures into my document. The whole thing is close to a page break, so I decided to split the figure via `\ContinuedFloat`. So just in case the second half of it can be moved to the next page.

The caption of the large figure with the subfigures is used as a kind of headline and placed on top. The subfigures get captions at the bottom, as well as the next, smaller figure. That is working fine so far.

But the numbers are a mess. The cross-references show, that the subfigures are numbered as "2a" instead of "1a" and so on. The following figure is then "3" instead" of "2". And the list-of-figures displays wrong page numbers for the first two subfigures.

This shows the current situation:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
    \captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,within=none}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{cleveref}
    \newcommand{\see}[1]{\cref{#1}, \cpageref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\sees}[2]{\crefrange{#1}{#2}, \cpagerefrange{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
There ist a huge amount of text, but I omitted it, because I was too lazy to type so many sentences.\par
There is some text and more text.\par

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption[short heading for the figure with subfigures]{Something like a heading for this figure containing subfigures}
    \label{fig:1}
    \vspace{1eM}
\subcaptionbox[short caption, first subfigure]{long caption, first subfigure\label{fig:1A}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleA.jpg}}
    \hfill
\subcaptionbox[short caption, second subfigure]{long caption, second subfigure\label{fig:1B}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleB.jpg}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox[short caption, third subfigure]{long caption, third subfigure\label{fig:1C}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleC.jpg}}
    \hfill
\subcaptionbox[short caption, fourth subfigure]{long caption, fourth subfigure\label{fig:1D}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleD.jpg}}
\end{figure}

Here is some text in between all these figures. 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{Example2.jpg}
    \caption{a figure with a wrong number}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

At the end there are some cross-references to these pictures. Since they are floating, it is not really at the end, but that is tolerable for now.\\
\see{fig:1}\\
\see{fig:1A}\\
\see{fig:1D}\\
\see{fig:2}\\
\sees{fig:1A}{fig:1D}\\
\sees{fig:1}{fig:2}\\
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

I tried to manage it via `\phantomcaption` and by redefining the position of the first caption. But since I am completely unaware of what is going on in the background I can't figure it out on my own. I'd really appreciate some help...

Comment: Adding `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` between the `\vspace` and the first `\subcaptionbox` fixes alle the numbering issues. I suspect that `subcaption` does something odd with the counters, but I could not track down the misbehaviour yet. (Strangely enough it does not occur in the `\ContinuedFloat`.)

Comment: That fix is really a relief since my deadline is coming closer. I am still interested in a 'final' solution though.

Comment: This seems to be a issue with `KOMA` -- using a normal `book` or `report` class, the numbers are correct, without needing `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}`

Comment: The problem is the order of the calls. When subcaptions are involved the intended syntax is to strictly place the `\caption` instruction at the end of the floating environment. The problem in fact disappears when you do `\begin{figure}[h]\subcaptionbox...\hfill\subcaptionbox...\caption...\label...\end{figure}`. I'll recommend to you to do it that way as it is the most clean fix and you are placing the captions below when you have single figures anyways.

Comment: `documentclass[captions=figureabove]{scrreprt}` and done.

Comment: @Johannes_B As explained I need a single caption on top of the pictures while all the other ones should remain at the bottom.

Comment: Just noticed that reading the answer below. Ruben is right, that is highly inconsistent and the  reason the numbering breaks. You can use `\KOMAoption{captions}{figureabove}` and `\KOMAoption{captions}{figurebelow}` as needed.

Comment: @Johannes_B Addressing the KOMA-settings sounds like the logical consequence. But it does affect the captions of the subfigures as well and these should remain at the bottom. I would omit the very first caption completely but it labels the subfigures as "sampling locations" and I need to refer to that later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class use `\captionabove` inside a group and remove `\vspace{1em}`:

```
\begingroup
  \captionabove
    [short heading for the figure with subfigures]
    {Something like a heading for this figure containing subfigures}%
    \label{fig:1}%
\endgroup
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
  \captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,within=none}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \newcommand{\see}[1]{\cref{#1}, \cpageref{#1}}
  \newcommand{\sees}[2]{\crefrange{#1}{#2}, \cpagerefrange{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
There ist a huge amount of text, but I omitted it, because I was too lazy to type so many sentences.\par
There is some text and more text.\par

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begingroup
    \captionabove
      [short heading for the figure with subfigures]
      {Something like a heading for this figure containing subfigures}%
      \label{fig:1}%
  \endgroup
  \subcaptionbox
    [short caption, first subfigure]
    {long caption, first subfigure\label{fig:1A}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleA.jpg}}
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox
    [short caption, second subfigure]
    {long caption, second subfigure\label{fig:1B}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleB.jpg}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \subcaptionbox
    [short caption, third subfigure]
    {long caption, third subfigure\label{fig:1C}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleC.jpg}}
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox
    [short caption, fourth subfigure]
    {long caption, fourth subfigure\label{fig:1D}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleD.jpg}}
\end{figure}

Here is some text in between all these figures. 
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics[width=7cm]{Example2.jpg}
  \caption{a figure with a wrong number}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

At the end there are some cross-references to these pictures. Since they are floating, it is not really at the end, but that is tolerable for now.\\
\see{fig:1}\\
\see{fig:1A}\\
\see{fig:1D}\\
\see{fig:2}\\
\sees{fig:1A}{fig:1D}\\
\sees{fig:1}{fig:2}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

**Addendum 2016-04-24 (by Axel Sommerfeldt)**

Additional explanation why using `\captionabove` solves this issue:

The counter is usually incremented at `\caption` (and not at `\begin{figure}`). While this simple rule is fine having only usual captions, having sub-captions makes all of this more complex since one can have zero to N captions within a figure, and `\subcaptionbox` (or `subfigure` environment) must know to which `\caption` it belongs. Otherwise `\ref` to a sub-caption would give a wrong result, and the list entry in the List of Figures would be incorrect, too. So when having sub-captions, the `figure` (or `table`) counter get sometimes incremented at the caption and sometimes at the sub-caption. For a correct increment of the `figure` counter the sub-caption must know if it belongs to a main-caption in front of it, or a main-caption coming after it.

Regarding your case: `\caption` usually means `\captionbelow` in a document using a KOMA-Script class, and so the first `\subcaptionbox` increments the figure counter additionally, assuming it belongs to a (future) `\caption` coming after it. For that reason this will be fixed by using `\captionabove` instead of `\caption` (or `\captionbelow`): This way `\subcaptionbox` knows it belongs to the (past) `\caption` typeset in front of it, and this way it does not increment the `figure` counter anymore.

Comment: Feels less messy than manipulating the counter, thanks for solving my problem! I don't understand why it works though... :D

Comment: @esdd Why `\captionabove` inside a group, usage of a group seems to be superfluous!?

Comment: @fortunecookies Since the explanation would be too long for a comment I will add it to esdd's answer right now.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt If I remove the group, the subcaptions are also above of the figures. A possibility without a group would be `\captionabove[...]{...}` followed by `\KOMAoptions{captions=signature}`. Thank you for the additional explanations.

Comment: @esdd Upps, yes, you are (of course) right. I tried it without extra group but didn't recognized the incorrect sub-caption position afterwards.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt My question was aiming towards the group. I was familiar with `\captionabove` but it did not work out as I hoped, probably because I did not know the term 'signature'. Thanks for your explanation nevertheless, it still gave me some new insights.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix you can use `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` right after the `\caption` call in your first float to ger the numbering right. In any case I recommend you to wrap this into some macro. Doing so, you are able to control every occurance of this fix at once. In my solution I called this macro `\StartSubcaptionsFloat`:

```
\newcommand{\StartSubcaptionsFloat}{\vspace{1em}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}}
```

As described you would then use it to mark the beginning of your subfigures, e.g.

```
\begin{figure}
  \caption[short heading for the figure with subfigures]
    {Something like a heading for this figure containing subfigures}
  \StartSubcaptionsFloat
  \subcaptionbox[short caption, first subfigure]
    {long caption, first subfigure\label{fig:1A}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleA.jpg}}
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox[short caption, second subfigure]
    {long caption, second subfigure\label{fig:1B}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleB.jpg}}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

If you then want to disable the fix later on you can redefine `\StartSubcaptionsFloat` to be simply the `\vspace` adjust, i.e.

```
\newcommand{\StartSubcaptionsFloat}{\vspace{1em}}
```

Probabilly your better options are to either change the class as the problem is related to the KOMA classes or to issue `\caption` at the end of your float. I strongly recommend to go with the last option, i.e. to say

```
\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox[short caption, first subfigure]
    {long caption, first subfigure\label{fig:1A}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleA.jpg}}
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox[short caption, second subfigure]
    {long caption, second subfigure\label{fig:1B}}
    {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ExampleB.jpg}}
  \caption[short heading for the figure with subfigures]
    {Something like a heading for this figure containing subfigures}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

as 1) you placed the captions below images in single floats (so it's a matter of consistency), 2) you should not mess with changing the class near the dealine and 3) it's defenetely the cleanest solution.

#### Addendum

See the answer by @esdd for a clean solution within KOMA.

Comment: I suspected the placement of the very first caption myself. As I explained; in this case it does not make sense to put it somewhere else. Putting it at the end of the first part of the figure will have it appearing in between the subfigures (looking odd). At the end of the continued float it will be on the next page after all the subfigures. That is even more messy because it explains the appearance of the subfigures. That is why I tried to redefine its position. But since it is KOMA-style to essentially put the caption where you put the call for it, it had no effect.