# How to customise subcaptions with `\documentclass{scrartcl}` that work inside no-float environments?

Tags: captions, koma-script, subcaption

**DISCLAIMER**: Yesterday, I posted [this question about subcaptions numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425696/how-to-change-subcaption-numbering/425699?noredirect=1#comment1065175_425699). The question received an excellent answer that works perfect for `\documentclass{article}`, but that fails whenever using `\documentclass{scrartcl}`. I posted a MWE with `\documentclass{article}` because I did not know that the package `subcaption` fails with `scrartcl`. Hence, I was suggested to either edit my question or ask a new one. Because the question already has an accepted answer that I think may be useful to other readers, I have left the other question as it is and I ask here a new one.

Consider the following (now correct) MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{Optimal Claims}\label{optimalclaims}
\medbreak
\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Resources/Plot1.pdf}
    \medbreak
    \captionof{figure}{Our Game}\label{our}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Resources/Plot2.pdf}
    \medbreak
    \captionof{figure}{mascu}\label{mascu}
\end{subfigure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Which generates the following output:

[image]

As you can see, I get `II.a` and `II.b`, and what I would get is `I.a.` and `I.b.` instead. Therefore, my question is: **how can I get `I.a.` and `I.b.` with `\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}` (that is, without `subcaption`)?**

**IMPORTANT**: I need a solution that works inside environments that allow no floats or, at least, a solution that is easy to adapt to such environments (as the accepted solution by Mico in [my original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425696/how-to-change-subcaption-numbering/425699?noredirect=1#comment1065175_425699)). I'm namely thinking about `mdframed` environments, in which I'm writing my proofs.

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time and effort. I'm sorry for the confusion with my first question.

Comment: If the use of `mdframed` is important in your question, include it in your MWE.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To keep the MWE really simple, I did not include it in the question; I just took the figures out of the float environment (this suffices for the question to be complete; `madramed` is only relevant to the extent that does not allow floats in it). I hope the MWE is OK now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the caption is set above the pictures use `\captionabove`. For explanations see the comments by Axel Sommerfeldt at the end of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304842/43317).

In a non-float environment you have to add `\captionsetup{type=figure}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \captionabove{Optimal Claims}\label{optimalclaims}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Plot1.pdf}
    \medbreak
    \subcaption{X}\label{our}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Plot2.pdf}
    \medbreak
    \subcaption{Y}\label{mascu}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{mdframed}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \captionsetup{type=figure}
      \captionabove{Optimal Claims}\label{optimalclaims2}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Plot1.pdf}
        \medbreak
        \subcaption{X}\label{our2}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \hfill
      \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Plot2.pdf}
        \medbreak
        \subcaption{Y}\label{mascu2}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using `\captionabove` I solve the issue if the pictures are in a float environment. But inside `mdframed` environments in which floats are not allowed, the solution you suggest does not work. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. That solved the question. I will edit my question to highlight the need of the answer working on a non-float environment.

Comment: @Héctor If you place all your figure captions above the content, you could use the KOMA-Script document class option `captions=figureheading`. (Afterwards ' \caption` is sufficient, no need for using `\captionabove`.)